# PERT/CPM Java implementation

Tags: java, graph, scheduling

I need help regarding the development of a software that solves these kind of problems. I have a pretty clear understanding of the theory behind it but I don't know how to translate it to code (I'm not a programmer). I've read some posts here about graph-handling libraries like JUNG, JGraph and JGraphT but reading the documentations hasn't been of help to me.

So, people who have worked with these libraries, which one do you recommend me to work with? I'm not planning to visualize them (altho that would be nice but it's not my priority), I just need to work with them, perform operations and get the results on the console.

I appreciate every bit of help and guidance you can give me, thanks in advance.

UPDATE: After some more reading of the javadocs of the libraries I mentioned before, I realized that the problem I have is that I need to add "weight" (execution time, actually) to my vertices (tasks), but all the interfaces supplied by these libraries only let me add weight to the edges, what can I do?

Comment: Are you actually studying PERT and CPM or just throwing the words at us? A graph with weighted vertices can be translated easily to a graph with weighted edges. PERT uses weighted edges and CPM uses weighted vertices.